# How can I ignore todo of specific file in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I have a file `bundle.js` file which has a lot of todos. I just want to ignore all the todos from this file. How can I do so in `Atom` editor with `Todo Show` package?

[image]

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can ignore all the todo from this file in two ways:

---

- add this specific file to your .gitignore file
- add the path of your file in the array `ignoreThesePaths`

For the second solution in atom go to Preferences->Packages->Todo Show->Settings.
You just need to add your path to the list (build\bundle.js in your case)

[image]

Comment: if I use add it in `.gitignore` file, I wouldn't be uploaded to git! All I want is that it just ignores the todos not the file

Comment: Then use the second method, I added explanations to my answer